# Is "a signature" or "signatures" when referring to multiple forms that have to be signed by a single person?

Tags: phrases

Is it "a signature" or "signatures" when referring to multiple forms that have to be signed by a single person?

> The forms require a signature from my brother.

> The forms require signatures from my brother.

Comment: The forms require my brother's signature.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there may be multiple documents requiring a signature, it sounds odd to say "signatures" from one person, because an individual's 'signature' is something *unique*. For example, if I saw an instance of my signature I would say "*that is my signature*", and not "that is *one of* my signatures"!

It would be better to say "the **forms** need to be **signed** by my brother".